# I'm trying to create a blog page with hugo it gives some annoying errors

Tags: powershell, markdown, hugo, toml

This is the config file

```
baseURL = "https://.github.io/"
languageCode = "en-us"
title = "Title"
theme="hugo-PaperMod"
[[params=]]
    [[homeInfoParams=]]
        Title= "Hi there wave"
        Content= "Can be Info, links, about..."

    [[socialIcons=]] 
        - name= "github"
            url= "<link>"
        - name= "<platform 2>"
            url= "<link2>"
```

This is the error on the powershell

```
ERROR 2021/08/15 17:40:30 "C:\Users\user\Desktop\blog\webapp\config.toml:5:9": unmarshal failed: toml: expected character U+005D
Rebuilt in 1 ms
```

I'm a total beginner in this area its most likely a basic thing but i can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR; Take the equals signs out of your config's toml.
P.s. Their are no equals signs in the [[]] statements.

Some advice:
If your code doesn't work, verify your code (validate)-
https://www.toml-lint.com/
If you don't understand the language syntax when the validator gives you   errors, check your specific misunderstanding in that language (that linter   will give you more data).
https://github.com/toml-lang/toml
As it's hugo and they have pre-built config files for you to review, review   what other people have done that does work:
https://gohugo.io/getting-started/configuration/#readout
https://themes.gohugo.io/

Additional, when looking at your question and the wider sphere:

1. Why do you say annoying error? English isn't my first language. But it's telling you that your toml is miswritten so it can't parse it. The more accurate information you give the more accurate information you will get back from others in the field.
2. So, a better example would be (and this is an idea):
   "HUGO Config.toml errors, uncertain of correct syntax"